# Is it a Bad practice to use same View at several events only by hiding and changing fields?

Tags: android, xml

Assume if there is a reset password button where user reset the password, and there is edit account button for a already logged in user, For a fact in my case When I reset password My interface includes few components(TextViews,EditTexts)which is normally not in account settings interface, So is it a good practise if I already make those components in my account settings inteface and set them invisible? And then only when user press Rest those get visible?.

*It would look little messy like that. Or is it good to have seperate interfaces?

*And if I keep seperate interfaces how does it affect to my project fucntioning overall? Does it make slow or Size(MB) gets bigger or what?

*I think good program practice to use less interfaces and re-use is it right ?

The below image is roughly interface design which addresses my question. Circled are common features. I know if I do this I have to control everything through my code through IDs. So any help would be so appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I guess it should depend on how often we tend to flip layouts. Considering standard number of times ,  i believe its fine to add remove views AND NOT inflate views everytime. Just get the feeling inflating is a lil more expensive.

Comment: Just add and remove the views as needed as I get the feeling that your view hierarchy isn't big enough to really make a difference either way(I think you're prematurely optimizing stuff). Using the same views will make changing stuff around way harder than inflating a modified layout file.

Comment: it would be harder but it is good for programming right? once when someone is capable of handling the thing. Application merely contain fewer files to store inside. It also is good right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuse is a good practice and I'm personally in favor of your approach. But reusing the layout files can also be tricky, considering the cases in which you're loading a rather large layout file and hiding most of it ! In this cases, loading unwanted hierarchy of this layout, poses a strain on performance.

Keep your layout files, as flat as possible. By this I mean that, nested layouts are more time and resource-consuming to render. Designing with the least views possible, is of course a skill and you should work on it.

Also, take advantage of tools like TraceView and ..., to measure the performance of your application, when using different layout files or reusing them.

**For greater details on how to analyze and measure your application performance, [you can read this article.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTools/article.html)**

Comment: I hope this is the answer I was looking for. Appreciate this.

Comment: that's a good article. study it and use the tools for precise analysis and testing of your approach